# CreatePopupMenu and mouse wheel scroll

Tags: c++, winapi, menu, scroll, mousewheel

I would like to add mousewheel scroll to a menu of an open source app (beacause in my case the menu gets taller than screen).

The menu is created by CreatePopupMenu api call, populated by AppendMenu then added to toolbar by m_toolbar.SetMenu.

Is it even possible, and if so what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Native menus don't support scrolling.  You really want to consider creating sub-menus so this doesn't become utterly unusable.

Comment: I would recommend to give up with this idea.

Comment: Ok then, is it possible to add combobox to a native toolbar?

Comment: Yes, there are numerous articles available on this topic -- if you need answers to specific questions, edit the question above appropriately